# Webpack-Dev-Server keeps looking for src folder

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a simple html page with one script added and trying to use webpack dev server to load the page, but it keeps returning this error to me `ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 ./src Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\etc\Desktop\etc'`
and this is my `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'source/index.html'),
    port: 3000
  }
}
```

and I'm running this command `webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In default, Webpack4 use `./src` to be the enter path.
If `'C:\Users\etc\Desktop\etc'` doesn't include `./src`, you can specify your enter path by `webpack.config.js`, Could you try this :

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  // the enter path
  entry: "YOUR APP PATH",
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'source/index.html'),
    port: 3000
  }
}
```

And it is easy to config, please see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/

Comment: tried this, getting an error saying that devServer doesn't have key `entry`

Comment: @SirajKakeh I had fixed my answer, please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you out of this problem :
Please go to your project and try running `"npm run dev"`
if it throws error : Like mentioned above please run below command ,

```
nano `package.json`
```

or

```
vi package.json
```

and see if it has not "dev" task inside "scripts" as below , then please see if it is in "start"

```
"scripts": {
"build": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.config.prod.js --colors",
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack/webpack.config.dev.js"
}
```

or

```
"scripts": {
"build": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.config.prod.js --colors",
"start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack/webpack.config.dev.js"
}
```

Then run command like

```
npm run dev
```

or

```
npm run start
```

based on it.
Hope it will help. Mark it as resolved if it answered query.
Please suggest for improvements, appreciated! .